# Can't change title of modal using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, modal-dialog

I've created a resource database using Laravel, and have the option to (flag, edit, and/or delete) a resource. When I hit the 'flag' button a modal pops up for you to add input as to why you're flagging the resource.  I'd like for the title of the modal to show which resource was clicked, and I have it working, but in this instance I cannot change the title of the modal regardless of which resource I flag.  Here's some of my code, hopefully it'll be more clear.

**Resource View**

```html
@foreach($resources as $resource) @foreach ($resource->locations as $location)
<tr>

  <td> <a class="btn btn-small btn-default" style="float:right; margin-right:5px;" href="{{ URL::to('resource/addToCart/' .$resource->Resource_ID) }}">+</a> {{ $resource->Name }}</td>
  <td>{{ $resource->Description }}</td>
  <td>{{ $location->Address }}</td>
  <td>{{ $location->City }}</td>
  <td>{{ $location->Zip_Code }}</td>
  <td>{{ $location->County }}</td>
  <td>
    <button type="button" class=" msgBtn btn btn-default" style=" display:inline; margin-right:auto;"><a href="pages/editresources/{{$resource['Resource_ID']}}">Edit</a>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class=" msgBtn2 btn btn-default" id="flagged" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#flagResource" style="display:inline; margin-right:auto;"><a href="#">Flag</a>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class=" msgBtn3 btn btn-default" style="display:inline; margin-right:auto;"><a href="setdelete/{{$resource['Resource_ID']}}">Delete</a>
    </button>
  </td>

</tr>
@endforeach 
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

So, when the middle button is clicked, it brings up the modal which looks like this

**Modal View**

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="flagResource"
         tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
         aria-labelledby="flagResourceLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close"
                            data-dismiss="modal"
                            aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"
                        id="flagged" style="text-align:center;"> {{ $resource->Name }}
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', url('FlagsController@addFlag'), $resource->id ]) !!}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('reason', 'Reason for Flag: ') !!}
                        {!! Form::textarea('Reason', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('comments', 'Other Comments: ') !!}
                        {!! Form::text('Comments', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button"
                            class="btn btn-default"
                            data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <span class="pull-right">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:5px;">
            Submit
          </button>
        </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So whenever I click flag on ANY resource, It shows this:

[modalExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNOpA.png)

I can't figure out why it keeps showing up that as my title. Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modal uses this data:

```
$resource->Name
$resource->id
```

You probably have the modal somewhere after your foreach in your code, so `$resource` is filled with data from the last row in this loop:

```
@foreach($resources as $resource) @foreach ($resource->locations as $location)
       <td> <a class="btn btn-small btn-default" style="float:right; margin-right:5px;" href="{{ URL::to('resource/addToCart/' .$resource->Resource_ID) }}">+</a> {{ $resource->Name }}</td>
@endforeach
```

What you should do is send more data to the modal so it can show the correct information. So in your loop you should attach more data for every row.

I am assuming you are using bootstrap for the modal. In version 3.2.0 you can do something like this to add this data:

```
<a href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-resource-id="{{ $resource->Resource_ID }}" data-resource-name="{{ $resource->Name }}">Flag</a>
```

And use javascript to get the variables and set them in your modal instead of using `$resource->Name`.

```
$('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var resourceId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('resource-id');
    var resourceName = $(e.relatedTarget).data('resource-name');
    $(e.currentTarget).find('#resourceId').val(resourceId);
    $(e.currentTarget).find('#resourceName').val(resourceName);
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what you mean by sending more data to the modal.  Do you mean instead of just having the title, I should include the description, address, etc.. in the modal as well?  I didn't have javascript at first, to include javascript do I just put that code in between `<script>` tags? Thanks.

Comment: Ok let me try to explain it like this: The modal is just a piece of html code, it does not know what `$resource` you clicked on to flag. 

You tried to use `{{ $resource->Name` }} but you have a whole list list of names in `$resources` on this page. 

So you should use javascript to see what `$resource` you clicked on and send its information to the modal using `data-resource-name="{{ $resource->Name }}"`.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but as far as the javascript goes, can i just place it within the view i'm calling the modal in between `<script></script>` tags? Or do I have to put it in my layout and include it?

Comment: So you should add the `data-resource-name` and `data-resource-id` to every flag link, and also add the javascript in between `<script>` tags.This can be done in your template or in just this view. After that you still have to assign the data to your HTML with jQuery (i just used a quick example above using `#resourceId`)

Comment: So, if i've added the code you've suggested, and have this `<h4 class="modal-title" id="flagModalLabel" style="text-align:center;"></h4>`  and this in my <script> `$("#flagModalLabel").html($(e.relatedTarget).data('title'));`  how can I pass this into my HTML instead of using the `{{$resource->Name}}`? Sorry for pestering you, but it's driving me crazy.

Comment: First of all check if the data is available in the javascript, What happens if you do `console.log($(e.relatedTarget).data('title'))` in your javascript? Is that the correct title in your console?

Comment: I figured it out, in my javascript I wasn't calling the right variable.  I had it as `#flagged` instead of the correct one `#flagResource`.  Now I'm having an  issue where it won't accept my input that I entered through the form.  Could you possibly help with that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40073448/trying-to-add-data-to-database-but-its-coming-in-as-null