# Trying to add data to database, but it's coming in as Null

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm trying to add 2 fields of input through a modal, but once I hit submit I get an error message saying

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'Flag_Reason' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `Flagged` (`Flag_Reason`, `Other_Comments`) values (, ))
```

Here's some of my code pertaining to the issue.

**Resource & Flag Models**

```
class Resource extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Resources';

    protected $primaryKey = 'Resource_ID';

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'Name',
        'Description',
        'Misc_Info'
    ];

    protected $guarded = [];

    /** A resource can have many locations */

    public function locations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Location', 'ResourceLocation', 'Location_ID', 'Resource_ID');
    }

    public function flag ()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Flagged');
    }



class Flagged extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Flagged';

    protected $primaryKey = 'Flag_ID';

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'Flag_Reason',
        'Other_Comments',

    ];

    protected $guarded = [];


}
```

**Resource View (modal is triggered in this view)**

```
<table class=" display table table-hover table-bordered" , id="resource">
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Address</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach($resources as $resource) @foreach ($resource->locations as $location)
    <tr>
      <td> <a class="btn btn-small btn-default" style="float:right; margin-right:5px;" href="{{ URL::to('resource/addToCart/' .$resource->Resource_ID) }}">+</a> {{ $resource->Name }}</td>
      <td>{{ $resource->Description }}</td>
      <td>{{ $location->Address }}</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" id="submitFlag" class=" msgBtn btn btn-default" style=" display:inline; margin-right:auto;"><a href="#flagResource" data-toggle="modal" data-resource-id="{{ $resource->Resource_ID }}" data-resource-name="{{ $resource->Name }}">Flag</a>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="flagResource" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="flagModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="flagResourceLabel" style="text-align:center;"> Flagged
                    </h4>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        {!! Form::open(array('url'=>'flags', 'class'=>'form', 'method'=>'POST')) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="reason" class="control-label">Reason for Flagging:</label>
          {!! Form::text('reason', null, array('class'=> 'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Reason')) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="comments" class="control-label">Other Comments:</label>
          {!! Form::text('comments', null, array('class'=> 'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Comments')) !!}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <span class="pull-right">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:5px;"><a href="setflag/{{$resource['Resource_ID']}}">Submit</a></button>
                    </span>
      </div>
      {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  $('#flagResource').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var submitFlag = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var resourceName = submitFlag.data('resource-name');
    var resourceId = submitFlag.data('resource-id');
    var modal = $(this);
    modal.find('.modal-title').text(resourceName);
  });
</script>
```

**Flag Controller**

```
public function addFlag($id) 
{ 
  $flag = Flagged::create(Request::only( 
  'Flag_Reason', 
  'Other_Comments' )); 

  $flag->save(); \Session::flash('flash_message', 'Flagged!'); 
  return back(); 
}
```

Once I input a reason and comments for the flag, I get the above message.  What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT ROUTES**

```html
Route::get('flags', 'FlagsController@index');

Route::post('resource', ['as' => 'resource', 'uses'=>'FlagsController@postFlag']);

Route::get('flags/edit/{Resource_ID}', 'FlagsController@editResource');

Route::patch('flags/edit/{Resource_ID}', 'FlagsController@updateResource');

Route::get('setflag/{Resource_ID}', 'FlagsController@addFlag');

Route::get('pages/editresources/rmflag/{Resource_ID}', 'FlagsController@removeFlag');

Route::get('pages/editresources/rmdelete/{Resource_ID}', 'FlagsController@removeDelete');

Route::get('setdelete/{Resource_ID}', 'FlagsController@addDelete');
```

Comment: You're attempting to retrieve input named `Flag_Reason` and `Other_Comments`, but the name of the inputs on your form are `reason` and `comments`.

Comment: Ok, I see, but in my controller do I write something like this? `"Flag_Reason" => Request::get('reason');`

Comment: You could do it that way. Try it, see if it works.

Comment: I tried it's giving me an error after `Flag_Reason` and `Other_Comments` saying a `)` is expected.

Comment: You should be using array notation like so: `Flagged::create(['Flag_Reason'=>Request::get('reason'), 'Other_Comments'=>Request::get('comments')]);`

Comment: It's still giving me the same error, It must be because it's not getting the data for some reason, but I don't know why.

Comment: No, it's a syntax error. You probably have a stray character somewhere in your Controller code.

Comment: My controller code is exactly what I pasted though, `public function addFlag($id)
    {
        $flag = Flagged::create([
            'Flag_Reason'=>Request::get('reason'),
            'Other_Comments'=>Request::get('comments')]
        );
        \Session::flash('flash_message', 'Resource Flagged');
        return back();
    }` There's no stray characters in it.

Comment: Ok, where is the error coming from, then? When it says `a ) is expected`, there should be a file name somewhere in the stack trace.

Comment: I should have clarified, the error i'm getting is `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation` not the `)` error one.

Comment: What do you get from `dd(Request::all());`?

Comment: I get an empty array `[ ]`.

Comment: That's a problem. No input is being passed from your form to your controller method. Can you also post the contents of your routes file? Also, what version of Laravel are you running?

Comment: I put the `dd(Request::all())` before `$flag = Flagged::create([
            'Flag_Reason' => Input::get('reason'),
            'Other_Comments' =>Input::get('comments')]);` so, maybe that's why I'm getting nothing passed, but if I put it after that bit of code, I get the `SQLSTATE[23000]` error. Here are my routes pertaining to the flags functionality  `Route::get('flags', 'FlagsController@index');`, `Route::get('setflag/{Resource_ID}', 'FlagsController@addFlag');`, and a few for edits and delete flags. I'm running on 5.2.39

Comment: Are those ALL of your routes? If so, that's part of the issue. It looks as if your form is POSTing to /flags, but the route associated with /flags is set to respond to GET requests and uses the `FlagsController@index` method in your controller. Just to be certain, edit your question with the *entire* routes file. Your `FlagsController@addFlag` method is also set to respond to a GET request on /setflag, but I think there's more to the issue than what you've given us.

Comment: I've edited my original question to include my Flag Routes.

Comment: So, I've got it to add to my database by correcting my routes `Route::post('resource', ['as' => 'resource', 'uses'=>'FlagsController@postFlag']);`

Comment: Beat me to it! Yes, in order for routes to respond in the way you would expect, they need to match the signature of the form that's submitting the information. POST for post requests, and GET for get requests.

Comment: It's still submitting an empty string and null into my database fields `Flag_Reason ` and  `Other_Comments ` respectively though. So, it's still not recognizing my input.

Comment: Here's my full routes for the page, `Route::get('viewResource', 'FlagsController@addFlag');` and `Route::post('resource', ['as' => 'resource', 'uses'=>'FlagsController@postFlag']);` with the form open looking like this `{!! Form::open(array('route'=>'resource', 'class'=>'form', 'method'=>'POST')) !!}` I get the success flash message, but checking my database through workbench I have an entry, but nothing in the fields.

Comment: I figured it out, I was using the wrong query. I was using `Flagged::create->all()` instead of  `Flagged::create([
            'Flag_Reason' => Input::get('reason')` Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: Good on you, man! Feel free to post as an answer in case others have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing this in my controller :

```html
$flag = Flagged::create(Request::only( 
  'Flag_Reason', 
  'Other_Comments' ));
```

to this:

```html
    public function postFlag()
    {
        $flag = Flagged::create([
            'Flag_Reason' => Input::get('reason'),
            'Other_Comments' =>Input::get('comments')]);
        $flag->save();

        \Session::flash('flash_message', 'Flagged!');

        return redirect('resource');

    }
```